# Sql Server - Any special way to insert so that in one column the value was the same, while in the other varied?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, insert

I need to insert into a simple table with two columns.

The first column has to contain the same value from row to row, while the second has to hold the various values from a source table. So it all should look like this:

[image]

Question is - is there a way to make a set-based insert in this case? The way I do it now is simply iterate through the rows of the source table. Or it's also possible to use cursors, only I'm not sure which is best.

But still this is iteration.

Any means to get around this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: give us your insert statement. btw use `INSERT INTO <target> (Col1,Col2) SELECT 1,<colname> FROM <source>`

Comment: Use a [table-valued parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know your static value ahead of time, you could do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO targetTable(Col1, Col2)
SELECT 1, yourColumn
FROM sourceTable
WHERE <condition>
```

This is assuming that `1` is your static value. It can be replaced with the real value, or a variable, depending on the specifics of your query.

Answer (score 2):

```
insert into dest_tab(col1, col2)
select 1, col2
from src_table
where ....
```